# router.get no funciona

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy haciendo lo ejercicios del libro Get Programing with Node js de Johnatan Wexler, en la lección 19 se inicia el uso de express.Router(), pero las rutas no funcionan, en contraste con app sí funcionan, qué estoy haciendo mal?

Estas son las definiciones:

```
const express = require("express"),
  app = express(),
  router = express.Router()
```

y esta son las rutas:

NO FUNCIONAN

```
router.get("/users/new", usersController.new);
router.post("/users/create", usersController.create);
```

SI FUNCIONAN

```
app.post("/users/create", usersController.create);
app.get("/users/new", usersController.new);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No funcionan porque no estás usando el objeto `router` que estás instanciando.

El objeto [`Router`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router) de [`express`](https://expressjs.com/), *es una instancia aislada de middlewares y rutas*, por lo tanto para que tu aplicación conozca de su existencia debes aplicarla usando el método [`use()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.use) de tu instancia de aplicación.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// creo una instancia de router
const router = express.Router();
// aplico las rutas que manejará mi router
router.get('/hola', (req, res, next) => {
  let greetings = req.query && req.query.name;
  if(greetings) {
    return res.send(`Hola ${greetings}!`);
  }
  return res.send('Hola Mundo!');
});

// aquí le indico que voy a usar los middlewares y rutas declarados en el objeto router
app.use(router);
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('App is listening.');
});
```

Debemos tener en cuenta que primero se crea la instancia de `router`, luego se declaran las rutas con sus respectivos middlewares y de último se pasa el objeto `router` como argumento en `app.use()`.

Tu código debería verse parecido al siguiente:

```js
const express = require("express"),
app = express(),
router = express.Router()


router.get("/users/new", usersController.new);
router.post("/users/create", usersController.create);

app.use(router);

//...
```

De esta forma tu aplicación debe funcionar correctamente.